# Can't implement filtering function (strtotime)

Tags: php, datetime, time, filter, filtering

Need advice in which way I need to dig with filtering problem.

I have records with sport events, each sport event have columns for event start time, and event end time:

Event #1
Start time: 09:00 (time_from)
End time: 12:00 (time_to)

Format for time in database is HH:MM.

Then I have filter page, where user can set time range for event time, to show all events going on 09:45 - 11:45 )

I am trying to filter events in user specified range by converting filter input and database values to seconds but it is not working fully:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($sport_events as $event)
{
    // check if the event is in user specified range
    // $filter_time is already converted to strtotime previously

    if( strtotime($event['time_from']) >= $filter_time_from_seconds && strtotime($event['time_to']) <= $filter_time_to_seconds )
    {
        // do nothing
    } else {
        // unset sport event
        unset($event[$i]);
    }
    $i++;
}
```

It may output results if user enter 09:00 and 12:00, but not 10:00 and 11:00 for example which is in the range.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you output the values for those vars?

Comment: If we follow our example, then $filter_time_from_seconds, and $filter_time_to_seconds is 10:00:00 1530860400, 11:00:00 1530864000

Comment: Sorry for the delay... and $event['time_from'] value is 9:00 ? or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: 09:00 not 9:00 to be correct

Comment: So if event time is 9:00 and filter time is 9:45 then you won't find a match.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing 'from_date' and 'to_date' in TIME format into database then you can directly pass the user's input filter data into MySQL query like

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE-NAME WHERE `from_date` >= '10:00' AND `to_date` <= '12:00';
```

You don't require loop to check the result set in PHP condition.